# AppCenter Build failed with Custom flavours

Tags: android, gradlew, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to build and distribute an app in the app center from an Azure branch.

The App Center is trying to build a different variant and I don't know how I can change it.

This is the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:process{clientName}DevReleaseGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name '{package}'
```

and this is the default YAML that is running (and I don't know how to change this default Gradle)

```
  - task: Gradle@1
    displayName: Gradle Task
    inputs:
      tasks: 'clean :app:assembleRelease '
      options: >-
        -DAPPCENTER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="$(keystorePassword)"
        -DMOBILECENTER_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="$(keystorePassword)"
        -DAPPCENTER_KEY_ALIAS="$(keyAlias)"
        -DMOBILECENTER_KEY_ALIAS="$(keyAlias)"
        -DAPPCENTER_KEY_PASSWORD="$(keyPassword)"
        -DMOBILECENTER_KEY_PASSWORD="$(keyPassword)"
      jdkArchitecture: x86
      publishJUnitResults: false
      sqAnalysisBreakBuildIfQualityGateFailed: false
```

Changing the following code should work, any help how can I change this or select my custom variant?

```
tasks: 'clean :app:assembleRelease '
```